# My app is crashed when load image from URL using Picasso and mvvm architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, picasso, circleci

I am using MVVM architecture and I want to load image from URL in `Fragment`. But it is crashed and show an error:

```
Required DataBindingComponent is null in class FragmentHomeBindingImpl. 
A BindingAdapter in delegation.app_multi.multimedia.model.student.Student is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. 
If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.
```

Below is my `CircleImageView` xml:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
                        android:layout_width="41dp"
                        android:layout_height="41dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_default_avt"
                        app:imageUrl="@{user.avt}"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_gr_profile"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_gr_profile" />
```

In class `Student`:

```
    @Bindable
    public String getAvt() {
        return avt;
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
    public void uploadImageFromURL(ImageView imgView,String url){
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imgView);
    }
```

And `onCreateView()` in my Fragment:

```
    FragmentHomeBinding fragmentHomeBinding;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        view = fragmentHomeBinding.getRoot();
        sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(nameSharePreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        student = new Student();
        student.setAvt(sharedPreferences.getString("linkAvtCurr",null));
        student.setStudentCode(sharedPreferences.getString("stuCodeCurr",null));
        student.setFullName(sharedPreferences.getString("stuNameCurr",null));
        fragmentHomeBinding.setUser(student);
```

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

problem is here

```
    student.setAvt(sharedPreferences.getString("linkAvtCurr",null));
    student.setStudentCode(sharedPreferences.getString("stuCodeCurr",null));
    student.setFullName(sharedPreferences.getString("stuNameCurr",null));
```

in this line

```
sharedPreferences.getString("stuCodeCurr",null)
```

you are loading data from shared prefrences and if data is not exist , you're passing null to that object

so you can null check or simply replace code below with your own code

```
 FragmentHomeBinding fragmentHomeBinding;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility"})
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    view = fragmentHomeBinding.getRoot();
    sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(nameSharePreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    student = new Student();
    student.setAvt(sharedPreferences.getString("linkAvtCurr","null"));
    student.setStudentCode(sharedPreferences.getString("stuCodeCurr","null"));
    student.setFullName(sharedPreferences.getString("stuNameCurr","null"));
    fragmentHomeBinding.setUser(student);
```

Comment: No, I ensure that it never null. My app is only crashed when I keep ```app:imageUrl="@{user.avt}"``` in XML file. If I delete it, my app is not crashed